# Is it possible to create a new Apple Developer account and create new Apple ID at same time?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id, developer-program

I've been updating an app that is created under a different Developers account and its becoming a real hassle accessing it - especially since Apple introduced 2Factor authentication. I have solved that issue but it's still a pain when notification emails go through a third party.

So what I want to do is create a new developer account myself. But I DO NOT want to link it up to my current personal Apple ID or account - I want to keep that separate.

Is it possible to do this? Create a new apple developer account with a newly created Apple account with ID. Then I assume I need to add both to my iPhone so I can authenticate and gain access to the developer portal?

Does this sound right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the goal simply to have another account you can use to update the app in App Store Connect? If so, you do not need a developer account. All you need is for the owner of the developer account to invite you as a user and delegate access. Note that the invited account does not even have to be an Apple ID. This will grant you access to App Store Connect, but not all the resources of a full developer account. There are several roles and levels of permissions as detailed here: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

If you do need your own developer account, you must create the new Apple ID first, then enroll it in the developer program. You will have to sign into the new Apple ID from your iPhone initially to set a "trusted device" and enable two-factor (multiple Apple IDs can use the same trusted device). After you have set up your "trusted phone number" you can sign out from the new Apple ID and just use the SMS method for that account.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will follow the method you outlined to create my own developer account via a new Apple ID and sign it into my iPhone.